# Detect browser and os version

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to detect the browser and OS version using Angular. The default `window` method has been overridden with Angular's window function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package called ng2-responsive: https://github.com/ManuCutillas/ng2-responsive that can detect browsers and a lot of other stuff...

Comment: Very Neat!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/KoderLabs/ng2-device-detector

Provides the following properties, via Service

- browser
- os
- device
- userAgent
- os_version